# "Focus mode" key on keyboard to make something more useful

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

My question is short, but I really don't know where to ask relative information. Is it possible to reman "Focus mode" key on MacBook (top row, the same as F6) to something more useful (e.g., for me, to toggle WiFi connection)?

I already examinited **System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts**, but don't see such an option there. Maybe I have missed it or it is in a different place, or there is completely different way for this.